# jquery: photo slide in different way than programmed

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I've made some photos slide one after another through jQuery using the *slide effect* available in **jquery ui**, basically ***each photo has two sliding effects (one from left to right and another from bottom to top)***.

But I am facing a problem i.e **every time each photo slides with only one (first) sliding-effect followed by another photo with the second effect though there are two sliding effects for a single photo**

For some reasons its showing some jquery or jquery-ui error in StackOverflow editor so here's the one from codepen:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var imglst = 
    ["https://images.pexels.com/photos/4933/lake-animals-dogs-pets.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/36477/dogs-batons-play-bite.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/35638/labrador-breed-dogs-animal.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260",
    "https://images.pexels.com/photos/101635/pexels-photo-101635.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260"];
    
  var len = imglst.length;
  
  i=0;   
  
  setInterval(function slider() {
    if(i < len){
      $("img").replaceWith("<img src= " +imglst[i]+ " height= 250px  width= 100% >");
      $( ".sliding" ).effect( 'slide', {direction: 'up'} ,1000 );    
      $( ".sliding" ).effect( 'slide', {direction: 'right'} ,1000 ); 
    }
    else{
      i = -1;
    }
    i = i + 1;
  }, 1000);  
});
```

```css
.slideborder{
  border: 2px dotted blue;
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-top: 2.5%;
  margin-left: 20%;  
}

.sliding{
  margin-top: 3%;
  margin-left: 14%;
  height: 250px;
  width: 80%; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div class="slideborder">
   <div class="sliding"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/356378/pexels-photo-356378.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" height="250px" width="100%"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: i am really confused in embedding code from codepen. here's the direct link to codepen : https://codepen.io/iamrupak/pen/NJWdMX

Comment: not sure what you are expecting it to do? you have 2 commands that simultaneously do 2 things within the same second (1000 millisecond) when the image changes. For testing increase the delay between images to 5000 and reduce the animation to 500 each and you will see the same image appears from bottom and then again appears from left. So again... what do you want it to do? animate diagonally?

Comment: @NawedKhan thanks ... that worked
i thought that 1000ms parameter in setInterval was meant for the interval after those two effects occur for every image.